# Pass Arguments from directive to controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I've seen lots of these questions but haven't found a solution that works. here is a fiddle that doesn't work but should.

http://jsfiddle.net/cdparmeter/j2K7N/2/

Controller:

```
$scope.foo = function (textArray) {
    console.log(textArray)
};
```

Directive:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
        methodToCall: '&method'
    },
    template: "<div>
        <input ng-model='textToPush'/>
        <button ng-click='pushText'>Push</button>
        <button ng-click='finish'>Finish</button>
    </div>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.paragraphs = [];
        scope.pushText = function () {
            scope.paragraphs.push(scope.pushText);
            scope.pushText = "";
        }
        scope.finish = function () {
            scope.methodToCall(scope.paragraphs)
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <container data-method="foo">
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm building an array inside my directive that needs custom handling in the controller of the parent scope. I know I can throw a watch in the parent scope on a model I pass into my directive but that seems hackish and dirty. any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before answering your question I must say that your script contains a few errors:

1. You're binding the input to a variable called `textToPush`, and then using a different one inside the `pushText` function (`pushText`);
2. You're not setting the `ng-click` directive correctly; it should be `ng-click="pushText()"` instead of `ng-click="pushText"`. The same for `finish`;

Now, back to your question. In order to call a function of the parent scope passing arguments, you can get a reference to that function first, and then execute it:

```
scope.finish = function () {
  var func = scope.methodToCall();                
  func(scope.paragraphs);
}
```

Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/j2K7N/3/) of your script.

You could also do this, if you prefer:

```
scope.finish = function () {
    scope.methodToCall({value: scope.paragraphs});                                
}
```

But for this code to work you should change your markup to:

```
<container data-method="foo(value)"/>
```

Here's [another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2K7N/4/) showing the solution above.